# How do I put error checking into this code, and how do I make my top 3 score function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have an assignment atm which requires me to allow the user(teacher?) to: enter their class (a/b), let them put in the students names, grades, give a grade based on the integer that they put in and then record the grade into a list along with a student. Furthermore, it needs to allow the user to delete a student+value and display the average of each class's scores and then show the top 3 scores for students from both classes. This is where I am current at: http://pastebin.com/2S7rUqFF If you could help with the error checking (eg If the user inputs anything other than an integer for the score, then an error message will pop up and make them re-enter it) and help with the top 3 function (Can't get it to work) that'd be great! thanks

Comment: this is not a good way to post your question on stack overflow ... it is hard to read and most people will not follow the link ... and your link includes way way more code than you should post in a question ... please read the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

try adding exceptions and error handling as follows

```
def function():
    try:
        #your code

    except e as Exceptions:
        print(e)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html